# How to get the inner module of Unet?

Tags: pytorch

I created a `UNet` with the the [UnetGenerator](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/blob/master/models/networks.py#L235-L314). You can find the resulting structure [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/078ee01f43a13524f634eff1d87fe191).

1. How do I get the module `Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))`?
2. How do I get the module `(5): ConvTranspose2d(256, 64, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))`?

I want to get the inner modules to change the attributes of certain layers.
I tried something like `net.modules(i).modules(i)`, but it doesn't work. I refer the docs, I haven't get a good idea to do it.

My initial intention is to change the attributes of certain layers when training. I may add a custom layer `myLayer`, in which `self.mode='normal'`. When training, I hope I can change its attribute `myLayer.mode = 'capture'` to make it change its behaviour in training.

Comment: Could you please share, which code you are using to create UNet.

Comment: @McLawrence https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/blob/master/models/networks.py#L235-L314

Comment: I still do not quite understand, what you want to do exactly. You want to modify some parameters in certain layers? Could you try to edit your question and elaborate a bit.

Comment: @McLawrence I have elaborate it and improve formatting.

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers it would be appropriate to mark that one as correct such that this question stays no longer without accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

All the subclasses of nn.Module has an attribute called children. Which you will be able to access using the code below.

```
unet = UnetGenerator(512,512,4)
layers = list(unet.children())
len(layers)
```

For the network I created using the above code , I can access one of the layers inside the network and change the properties like below.

```
l = layers[0]
conv = list(l.children())[0][0]
conv.kernel_size = (2,2)
```

If you are training the network without using any pre-trained weights then you could make the changes in the source code before you create the network object.

Comment: One more question: As the channels are concatenated before the ConvTransposed2d. Does the first half channels receive the data from the bottleneck or the latter half?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the correct answer of Vishnu:

If you want to make fixed changes, it will be better to change the code before the network object is created.

However, an important thing to mention about `pytorch` is, that you can change the properties dynamically: Most Deep Learning Libraries like `tensorflow` use static graphs for performance reasons. That means the graph of the network is build once and executed every forward pass.

`pytorch`, on the other hand, uses dynamic computational graphs, meaning that for each forward pass the graph is build on the fly. This gives you opportunities to change the network architecture dependent on some varying parameters. 
You could for example decrease your kernel size if your loss falls under a certain value or your epoch is an odd number (I do not imply that these are sensible application). All these dynamic changes should happen in the implementation of the `forward` function, to which you can pass additional arguments, e.g.:

```py
class MyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(input_nc, output_nc):
        super().__init__()
        # define layers 
        # ...
        self.choice_A = nn.Conv2d(input_nc, output_nc, kernel_size = 3)
        self.choice_B = nn.Conv2d(input_nc, output_nc, kernel_size = 4)
        # continue init

    def forward(self, x, epoch):
        # start forward pass
        # ...
        if epoch % 2 == 0:
            x = self.choice_A(x)
        else:
            x = self.choice_B(x)
        # ...
        return x
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am wondering which half of channels accept the data from the skip connection, [forward](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/blob/master/models/networks.py#L310-L314), it seems it is the former part?

Comment: The relevant line is this one: `return torch.cat([self.model(x), x], 1)`. Cat concatenates in the order given by you. Thus, the channels from the skip connection are the latter ones, since x is the input you skipped right to the output.

Comment: My bad, it is late to see your comment. I pulled a request to that repo, [change the order of concanated channels](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/commit/6360df153e46d33b27c46f16c78d732ce2f475cf), However, the owner has merged it. Maybe he made a mistake.